# At what pressure is the triple point of ethane?

Tags: pressure, equation-of-state

Depending on source there are two givens for the triple point of ethane: 0.8 Pa or 1.1 Pa. Only one of them can be correct, which one is?

Comment: Could you share your sources?

Comment: Wikipedia and NIST webbook say 1.1Pa, that has to be correct.

Comment: @Safdar The 0.8 Pa value reportedly _is_ from the NIST, however no younger than from 1988.

Comment: Could the 0.8 value be outdated?

Comment: @Giovanni NIST reports 1.1 Pa-https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C74840&Mask=4. Can you share the link where you found that out?

Comment: @RobinSingh One source had been the Wikipedia page "Triple point" but I changed it to the 1.1 value. However, some days later I saw the 0.8 value on another site but I dunno which one anymore. I think the 0.8 value is simply outdated.